# Error serializing `something` returned from getServerSideProps in `some page`

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js

I'm working on a project using next.js. it has a dynamic route using getServerSideProps. You can pass query to this page. folder structure is category/[title]. So it accepts category/[title]?{some query} URL. But when I type it in address bar I receive this error:

[image]

This is getServersideProps function (getLotsInCategory() and getCategories() are data fetcher of firebase. They're working in the other pages perfectly):

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context:any) {
  
    let category:any=[]
    let query:any
    if(context.query!=undefined){
      query=context.query
    }
    
    let title=context.params.title;

    let lotsInCategory:any=[]
    try{
        console.log(query)
       lotsInCategory=await getLotsInCategory(title)
      
       if(query.subCategory!=undefined){
        lotsInCategory=lotsInCategory.filter((el:any)=>query.subCategory.includes(el.subCategory)==true)
       }
    
      const categories:any=await getCategories();

     category=categories.filter((el:any)=>el.categoryTitle==title)
    category=category[0]
    
   
    lotsInCategory= JSON.stringify(lotsInCategory)
 
    category=JSON.stringify(category)
    
    query=JSON.stringify(query)
    
    }
    catch(er){
        console.log(er)
       
    }
   
   
     
    

    
  return {
    props: {query,lotsInCategory,category} // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

I've tried .json() instead of JSON.stringify(), but I received the same error.

Comment: If you log `lotsInCategory` to the console (before stringifying it), what's the output?

Comment: @juliomalves well the main problem is that It sometimes works without error and sometimes you receive error. But when I receive error lotsInCategory  (before stringifying it), I see the empty array

Comment: @juliomalves now discovered an error in terminal: typeError:at async E:\next-project\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache.js:72:36
TypeError: response.filter is not a function

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found the real problem. I saw the real error in the terminal in vs code and it was denying permission from firebase. getLotsInCategory and getCategories are my firebase method that works in static pages prefect, But when I use dynamic pages I can't get data from the fire base . so this error solve by changing firebase configs!